# What is the execution flow of an await/async program in TypeScript/JavaScript or Python?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

For a while know I try to wrap my head around the **internals** of async/await. I am a C++ developer with focus on multithreading and this concepts interferes with how a C++ program is executed.

I do understand Promise objects, and the emphasis of concurrent != parallelism, and also the event loop. I can follow the demand to have a single-threaded application that concurrently executes different parts of the program but what "creates" an event on the event loop? Is it the `Promise` object? Or the `async` keyword? Or is it something in some I/O functions to not block?

The closest concept I know would be the Global Interpreter Lock in Python where several threads wait for a global lock, so Python executes in a round-robin method to let every thread execute a piece of code. But this concept doesn't require an event-loop, and e.g. in JS/TS there is only a single thread involved.

Can anyone help me out (or recommend a good resource), so I can understand the execution flow or how I can make sense of this? Thank you so much!

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html is a good read. It deals with C# but the underlying concepts will still apply to a browser. Replace C# with whatever language the browser is written in.

Comment: Thanks! This blog post is indeed getting closer to what I am referring to. I am just wondering if the event loop I e.g. see in Python is the way to implement this or if its just one of different ways to implement this (and therefore not mentioned in the C# blog)

Comment: Just for reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: Thanks you! That looks good, I could accept these two links as an answer

Answer (score -1):

If you understand a promise then async await is just syntactic sugar.

```
async function() {
  doStuff();
  const x = await getSomePromise();
  doStuffWithX(x);
}
```

is the same as

```
function() {
  doStuff();
  getSomePromise().then(function(data) {
    const x = data;
    doStuffWithX(x);
  });
}
```

The interpreter does the callback wrapping for you.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this concept, but what does "create" an event on the event loop here? Which thread executes or finalizes the Promise object?

Comment: When the promise is resolved the callback function is executed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, who "finishes" the Promise object? Which thread? The Promise object doesn't from 'pending' to 'finished' just by waiting. So my question would be, which thread resolves the pending object?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem here. In which order, is the resolve of the Promise executed with concurrent promises?

Comment: You are thinking about it all wrong, there is a single thread. Any block is executed until it is finished. Add in a while(true) {} and it is all over. There is no parallelism, task switching, just a single thread executing blocks. A block runs, then another, they get queued.

Comment: I totally understand but your last comment is important to me - "they get queued". What makes them being queue? Syntax? Or the fact that Promise objects are kind of special? Or the async keyword? Thats what I try to understand